# Non-blocking alternative to subprocess.wait() that is compatible with time.sleep()

Tags: python, time, subprocess, popen, blocking

I am trying to run a program that implements non-blocking subprocesses. The program works... if I don't include time.sleep(). However, with sleeping, the program runs each portion based on the minimal sleeping time. I need to run my code in the order in which it is written, while also sleeping, and without blocking.

The issue is something to do with the way the subprocess is running. Specifically, without the wait() method, it just treats the different processes as if they are the same process.

Below is the code for Main.py and Subprocess.py.

**Main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_process(0)
    def start_process(self, id):
        if id == 0:
            process = Popen([sys.executable, 'Subprocess.py', "0"])
            process.wait()   # Need to remove wait() so as to prevent blocking.
            self.start_process(1)
        elif id == 1:
            process = Popen([sys.executable, 'Subprocess.py', "1"])
            process.wait()   # Need to remove wait() so as to prevent blocking.
            self.start_process(2)
        elif id == 2:
            process = Popen([sys.executable, 'Subprocess.py', "2"])
            process.wait()   # Need to remove wait() so as to prevent blocking.
            self.start_process(3)
        elif id == 3:
            process = Popen([sys.executable, 'Subprocess.py', "3"])
            process.wait()   # Need to remove wait() so as to prevent blocking.
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_app = Main()
```

**Subprocess.py**

```
import sys
import time

class Subprocess:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.num = int(self.num)
    def start_sleep(self):
        if self.num == 0:
            time.sleep(3)
            print("I slept for 3 seconds")
        elif self.num == 1:
            time.sleep(2)
            print("I slept for 2 seconds")
        elif self.num == 2:
            time.sleep(10)
            print("I slept for 10 seconds")
        elif self.num == 3:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print("I slept for 1.5 seconds")

obj = Subprocess(sys.argv[1])
obj.start_sleep()
```

**Output needed, without using wait():**
after 3 seconds: `I slept for 3 seconds`
after 3 + 2 seconds: `I slept for 2 seconds`
after 3 + 2 + 10 seconds: `I slept for 10 seconds`
after 3 + 2 + 10 + 1.5 seconds: `I slept for 1.5 seconds`

**Output I get, without using wait():**
after 1.5 seconds: `I slept for 1.5 seconds`
after 3.5 seconds: `I slept for 2 seconds`
after 6.5 seconds: `I slept for 3 seconds`
after 16.5 seconds: `I slept for 10 seconds`

As you can tell, the output I'm getting shows that the 4 subprocesses are being treated as one.

Comment: Are you sure about those times you listed for the "Output I get" section?  Without using `.wait()`, all of the processes should start at the same time, and the "10 seconds" process (for example) should finish 10 seconds later.  If you want each process to start when the previous one finished, and you don't want to use `.wait()`, then the alternative would be to use `.poll()` periodically to determine when it finished.